# How to write simple SMPP server using Joomla in PHP

Tags: php, joomla, smpp

I want to write a program that will allow me to send SMS to mobile phones using my own site server to support my joomla site

Comment: Normally I would use an SMS api. You can search the web for bulk sms API providers. They will also provide the necessary documentation on how to pass the data like [this](http://api.textmagic.com/https-api/sms-api-php-wrapper)

Comment: You might want to check the extensions direcetory

Comment: Its seems that all the cost they put upon the API for us to use is too high so am looking if i can get a way of having one on my own... please can you help me out @Jm Verastigue

Comment: The only other way I know is by connecting a phone to a computer and using that to send messages. It's quite simple if you run the web server locally with the computer connected to the phone. The price per message is cheaper but you have to deal with the maintenance. You can also check with your local mobile provider if they offer bulk sms services. Normally local services are cheaper than the international ones.